# upload document not working as part of Continuous integration bamboo

Tags: protractor, bamboo

I am trying to validate PDF document upload functionality however it is working fine in local where it picks the path from local folder however it is failing as part of Bamboo+Sauce+Qtest integration execution.

```
Below is the code snippet i have used to upload the documentin local which is working fine : 

var path = require('path');
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../uploads/Replace.pdf");
element(by.css('input[type=file][ng-model="detailDocuments.selectedFiles.selectedIbl"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
browserActions.clickOn(applicants.uploadBtn('Replace'));

Below is the code snippet which i have used to upload document as part of CI.

var path = require('path');
var remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote');
browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../uploads/Replace.pdf");
 element(by.css('input[type=file][ng-model="detailDocuments.selectedFiles.selectedIbl"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
browser.sleep(2000);
browserActions.clickOn(applicants.uploadBtn('Replace'));
browser.sleep(3000);

In the bamboo it showing below error message: 

Failures:
build   18-Feb-2019 13:15:56    1) IEATA.2356*: validation_for_upload_or_replace_documents_IEATA-2356 IEATA-2356 step 4: verification of applicantdetails page
build   18-Feb-2019 13:15:56      Message:
build   18-Feb-2019 13:15:56    [31m    Failed: invalid argument: File not found : /opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/EQ-PBR-JOB1/regression/bws/uploads/Test.pdf
build   18-Feb-2019 13:15:56          (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.80)
build   18-Feb-2019 13:15:56          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)[0m
build   18-Feb-2019 13:15:56      Stack:
build   18-Feb-2019 13:15:56        WebDriverError: invalid argument: File not found : /opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/EQ-PBR-JOB1/regression/bws/uploads/Test.pdf
build   18-Feb-2019 13:15:56          (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.80)
build   18-Feb-2019 13:15:56          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 

The PDF documents are available in protractor/uploads.
```

Comment: Your error seems to indicate it is looking for the path `/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/EQ-PBR-JOB1/regression/bws/uploads/Test.pdf` but you say your code sets the absolute path as `path.resolve(__dirname, "../uploads/Replace.pdf")`. Is this a typo or are you working with both files `Replace.pdf` and `Test.pdf` in your test?

Comment: I am working on both the PDF one for upload and the other to replace the existing PDF.I know that the issue is related to the path.But my question is how to set the above path?Also, I have given path.resolve(__dirname, ....corresponding path) which it should pick the file.

Comment: Are you setting the path the same way for Test.pdf? That is the file that is throwing the error but I don't see it mentioned in your code. Also, I'm assuming these files are stored as part of your project, would you mind describing your projects folder structure and what is the current active directory the machine in is when protractor is launched on both environments?

Comment: Hi, the files are available in below folder path "InSprint-02112019\protractor\uploads" .Similar way i have the same folder structure in GIT as well. The main thing is it is able to pick the path of local folder and recognise the files and upload the PDF document but  when it comes to bamboo where it is not able to recognise the same path and files from the latest branch code of the GIT repository. The folder structure of both local and GIT remains same.

Comment: You say files are in `InSprint-02112019\protractor\uploads` but your error is looking for `regression/bws/uploads`. How are these paths related? Is there any chance you could upload a screenshot of you project folder structure which shows the location of the files ?